# What does Van Dalen mean when he writes "Show by 'algebraic' means"?

Tags: logic

In Exercise 1.3.1, Van Dalen asks us to verify certain properties like contraposition, Peirce's Law, and several others by 'algebraic' means. What does he mean by this? My first instinct is to use a truth table.

Comment: The Ex is 2.3.1, page 27. And see page 21: "The purely *algebraic* aspects have since then been studied in *Boolean algebra*. We will just mention a few of those *algebraic laws*." And see page 22: "We give some examples of *algebraic computations*, which establish a chain of equivalences." Thus, it means: to show that the formulas are tautologies, using logical equivalences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He very likely means: derive them as identities in a [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)) using the defining laws of such structures. Note he mentions such laws before and in Thm 1.3.1 as well.

E,g contraposition: $\phi \to \psi$ is (definitonally) equivalent to $\lnot \phi \lor \psi$ while $\lnot \psi \to \lnot \phi$ is equivalent to $\lnot \lnot \psi \lor \lnot \phi$ and these Boolean formulas are again equal to each other by commutativity of $\lor$ and double negation.